# Fetching both locally and globally installed nodejs modules

Tags: node.js

How do i find all the node modules installed? It should fetch both locally and globally installed modules.

`npm ls` fetches only locally installed modules.

---

Also is there a way just to list the module instead of the version number and dependencies associated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To just list all globally installed node module names, try this:

```
ls `npm root -g`
```

Answer (score 1):

to list out globally installed modules, try

```
npm -g ls
```

Comment: Thanks. can i get only the module names. I dont want the version number and dependencies associated.